QGIS CircularChart expression symbology
I was trying to recover some maps I did back in 2017 using QGIS 2.18.
The map was using Circular Charts, this is a part of a longer expression in the Geometry Generator:

CircularChart("NAirbnb",6,8,to_real(@Buffer),to_real(@MultFact))

I had 8 variables in a layer and each variable generated a line of a circular chart. I also used project variables to change the dimensions of the chart from there.
Here is the output:

The expression is no longer working because the CircularChart function is not known in my current QGIS version (3.34).
I could do a workaround using the centroid and generating lines from there at a certain angle but I'd like to know where did this expression go? I can't find anything in the Visual Changelogs.
Could someone explain when this function was removed and why?

Are you sure this was a native expression and not something introduced by a plugin?

I don't think it was a plugin. The function is called inside the layer symbology using a geometry generator expression. In any case, I cant' find anything on CircularChart anywhere. It is like this function existed just for me in a parallel universe.

I'll try to download QGIS 2.x and see if the expression works.

Guys, I'm so sorry. It was a custom function!! Now I remembered. However, the function didn't get stored in the project or anywhere I can find. I feel a bit stupid now, should I delete the question? Or do you want to put your suggestion of a custom function as an answer @Babel

Never heard of such a function. It must have been a custom function, user programmed with Python. Also QGIS Docu for version 2.18 does not know any function named CircularChart().
For many different types of charts in QGIS, have a look at Data Plotly Plugin.
